# Mapserver mapfile with multiple layers that pull from postgis only gives broken image

Tags: postgis, mapserver, mapfile

I'm trying to use this mapfile that I made:

```
MAP
  IMAGETYPE PNG
  EXTENT -90.000124 41.000032 -88.000044 42.000035
  SIZE 1600 800
  IMAGECOLOR 255 0 1 

OUTPUTFORMAT
  NAME png
  DRIVER AGG/PNG
  MIMETYPE "image/png"
  IMAGEMODE RGBA
  EXTENSION "png"
  FORMATOPTION "GAMMA=0.75"
 TRANSPARENT ON
END

LAYER
  NAME poly
  STATUS OFF
  TYPE POLYGON
  CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
  CONNECTION "host=127.0.0.1 dbname=matt user=postgres password=postgres"
  DATA "the_geom from g41088"
  OPACITY 50
    CLASS
      NAME g41088P
        STYLE
          COLOR 200 200 200 
          OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
        END
    END
END

#LAYER
#  NAME line
#  STATUS OFF
#  TYPE LINE
#  CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
#  CONNECTION "host=127.0.0.1 dbname=matt user=postgres password=postgres"
#  DATA "the_geom from g41088"
#   CLASS
#     NAME g41088L
#       STYLE
#         COLOR 0 0 0 
#       END
#   END
#END
END
```

But it only works when I have the second layer commented out. I can't figure out for the life of me what's wrong with it. I'm trying to do the same thing that [this tutorial](http://mapserver.org/tutorial/example1-2.html#example1-2) is doing, but with PostGis support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your

```
NAME line
```

is probably causing the error, as "line" is a reserved mapfile keyword. Try with

```
NAME "line"
```

As a rule of thumb, you should always quote strings in a mapfile, even though the parser does allow strings that are not a reserved keyword to be left unquoted.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to define the projection there or in the WEB section. Also it could be related to the mapserver executable, probably it's not located in the cgi-bin directory, so this isn't accessible in your HTML code. Try these links, especially the getCapabilities to see what error messages you get:

http://lists.maptools.org/pipermail/ms4w-users/2010-May/001541.html
http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20070821130754.GB1175@www.gisnet.com
http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/still-have-problem-when-add-postgis-layer-on-mapserver-mapfile-td4997860.html